# ForceBindIP: Couldn't run the specified command line?

Tags: networking, command-line, windows-10

I'm trying to bind two programs to two different networks like this:

```
ForceBindIP.exe (network1 ip) "C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\ts3client_win64.exe"
```

and

```
ForceBindIP.exe (network2 ip) C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\lol.launcher.exe
```

However, when I try to run the command in command prompt, I receive the error "Couldn't run the specified command line." I have the ForceBindIP dll file and .exe in System 32 and SysWOW64 but it doesn't seem to work.

The syntax I'm using seems to be correct, and I am using the admin cmd prompt so I'm a little bit lost of what could be the issue here. This method should work on Windows 10, so that shouldn't be a problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first command line won't work since you're trying to run the 64 bit TS3 client. ForceBindIP is only compatible with 32 bit apps for now.

(As of this edit, a 64 bit ForceBindIP is now available)

Comment: I realize a comment would be more appropriate, but the site won't let me comment yet :(

Answer (score 1):

#### I receive the error "Couldn't run the specified command line."

```
ForceBindIP.exe (network2 ip) C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\lol.launcher.exe
```

The above command is missing the <kbd>"</kbd>s around the last argument.

Try:

```
ForceBindIP.exe (network2 ip) "C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\lol.launcher.exe"
```

- Replacing `(network2 ip)` with the appropriate IP address.

---

#### ForceBindIP GUI to Easily Bind Windows Application to Specific Network Adapter

> It is important to enclose the full path of the program with a double quote because there are whitespaces in between the characters in the path.

Source [3 ForceBindIP GUI to Easily Bind Windows Application to Specific Network Adapter](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/bind-windows-application-to-specific-network-adapter-with-forcebindip/)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue for network2, but I still receive the error with network 1, which should have the appropriate quotations. This is the command: ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.0.2 "C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\ts3client_win64.exe"

Comment: @CannonSloan Check you have the path correct for network 1 ...